# I want to query Object from Parse Relation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    let relation = user!.objectForKey("friendsRelation")
    relation!.query().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error")
        } else {
            print("Users Retrieved")
        }
    }
```

I'm Learning iOS development, and this parse code is not working, as I want to get Objects from current user relations. The error it's showing is

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: You will need to avoid forced unwrapping, and instead try safe unwrapping using if..let construct aka optional binding. That will help you to figure out if any call is failing to return the needed object.

Comment: sorry I din't understand, can you type out the code ?? @Shripada

Comment: PFObject provides `relationForKey()`, for relation attributes.  Replace `objectForKey()` with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much safer version that you can try:

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
  if let relation = user.relationForKey("friendsRelation") {
    relation.query().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
      (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error")
      } else {
        print("Users Retrieved")
      }

    }
  }else{
    print("Failed to fetch relation")
  }
}else {
  print("Failed to get user object")
}
```

You can now debug and see if you fail to have the user object or the relation, if you can get both, then there might be some other issue. Also note as @danh pointed out you should be using relationForKey instead of objectForKey.